# Laravel form request class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, backend

I'm trying to create laravel form validation, so I created a form validation with the following code. The problem is that I'm getting an error *"Class App\Http\Requests\RegisterForm does not exist"* when I typehint the request in controller. Any help would be much appriciated. Thanks

**RegisterForm.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegisterForm extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name': 'required',
            'email': 'required',
            'mobile_number': 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterForm;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(RegisterForm $request) {

    }

    public function login() {

    }
}
```

Laravel version 5.7
NGINX
php7.2

Comment: run composer dump-autoload and then try

Comment: Is your file path right?

Comment: @ankitpatel yes I've tried running the command but still getting same error

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes I'm sure my path are right

Comment: Did it display the line of that error msg?

Comment: @TsaiKoga thanks for that replay it turns out the issue was caused by colon symbol in the rules 'name': 'required' instead of 'name'=> 'required'

Comment: Please close the issue when solved.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was caused by using colon (:) instead of => in rules array

```
return [
'name'=> 'required',
'email'=> 'required',
'mobile_number'=> 'required',
];
```